# Paypal standard IPN not updating event participant status or fee contributions

Tags: civievent, contributions, paypal, ipn

Just wondering if anyone is aware of a bug or any reason why Paypal Standard IPN notifications have suddenly stopped updating our event participant status to registered and the associated contribution record to complete?

I can see the IPN from Paypal hitting the server in the access logs and it is receiving a '200' status.

The IPN history in Papyal shows everything ok.

I can see the entry in the civicrm table in the database.

Everything seems to be fine apart from the fact that the participant records are not being updated to registered and the contributions are still showing as 'Pending transaction'?

It seemed to stop only a few weeks ago - not 100% sure but I did upgrade the system to the latest 4.6.18 version around the same sort of time.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Cheers,

Dave

Comment: Is this for all participants or just additional participants?  There was/is an issue with only the primary participant status being updated, not additionals.

Comment: Hi Aidan, Thanks for the info, I think it is primary participants. Do you have a link to an issue? Do you know what was causing it and whether it has been resolved?

Comment: Hi Dave, If your problem is with primary participants then that is different.  The issue we encountered was that when an IPN was received, the primary participant was correctly updated from Pending but the additional participants were not changed (4.6).  I don't think there is a Jira for that.  The issue is fixed in 4.7 as a result of other code enhancements but the git logs don't suggest it was intentionally fixing this problem.

Comment: Hi, we've upgraded to latest 4.7.x but we are still getting no changes to participant status and/or contribution records associated with event sign-ups from Paypal? Again, I cann see '200' status rows in my log files, I can see the entries in the civicrm_system_log table and nothing in the error logs.

Comment: I am seeing this entry in an error_log file in the extern directory (where the ipn.php file is).

[12-Jul-2016 10:22:19 Europe/London] PHP Warning:  ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /home/xyz/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line 45

Comment: An issue related on the Drupal module Webform CiviCRM https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/2611072#comment-13455779. That was your case?